# Is there a standard method for broadcasting a 1d numpy array along the first axis of a higher-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

My data often takes the form of

- a single numpy array made from a stack of N n-dimensional arrays of arbitrary shape (*e.g.* `data.shape = (N, a, b, c, ...)`, where `a, b, c, ...` are unknown ahead of time), and
- a corresponding 1d array of coefficients (*e.g.* `coefs.shape = (N,)`),
  which I need to broadcast along the first axis.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
sub_array_shape = 3, 3

# Random data representing arbitrary data from external source
raw_data = np.stack([np.random.randn(*sub_array_shape) for i in range(N)])
corrections = np.random.randn(N)
```

Now I need to broadcast the two arrays together to apply the correction to my data.
I've found two approaches that work:

1. Transposing the data before and after the operation like

   ```
   corrected_data = (raw_data.T + corrections).T
   ```
2. Padding the coefficient array with singleton dimensions like

   ```
   corrected_data = raw_data + corrections.reshape(-1, *(1,) * (raw_data.ndim - 1))
   ```

It seems to me that neither of these approaches are very elegant or readable, so I wonder if there's a better way.
Is there a standard method for solving this problem when working with numpy arrays?
If not, are either of the two methods I've shown preferred?

My main concern is the readability of my code, but I'd also be interested whether there is any performance difference between different approaches.

Comment: If it works, it's 'accepted'.  There isn't a numpy style book.  You could wrap (2) in a utility function. Also look at the code for `expand_dims`

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. I guess when I said 'accepted', I meant 'standard' (i.e. an approach that the majority of people adopt). I'll edit the question to make that clearer, cheers.

Comment: For readability I like to use `x[:,None,None]`, But obviously that doesn't work  in a context requiring a variable number of additions.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ambiguity, the broadcasting rules can add leading dimensions as needed, but trailing ones have to be explicit.  I don't think there's any "elegant" way of adding a variable number of trailing dimensions, though you cal always use a function wrapper to make any method "elegant".

So with 2 arrays:

```
In[41]: x = np.ones((3,2,4,5),int)
In [42]: y = np.arange(3)
```

The syntax that stands out to me as being a broadcasting adjustment is:

```
In [43]: z=y[:,None,None,None]    
In [45]: (x*z).shape
Out[45]: (3, 2, 4, 5)
```

But is doesn't lend itself to variable dimensions.

`reshape` is easier to do programmatically, as your (2) shows:

```
In [46]: z=y.reshape(-1,1,1,1); z.shape
Out[46]: (3, 1, 1, 1)
In [47]: (x*z).shape
Out[47]: (3, 2, 4, 5)
```

I was going to suggest `broadcast_to`, but that requires those trailing dimensions:

```
In [49]: z = np.broadcast_to(y,x.shape); z.shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 1
----> 1 z = np.broadcast_to(y,x.shape); z.shape

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py:413, in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    367 @array_function_dispatch(_broadcast_to_dispatcher, module='numpy')
    368 def broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=False):
    369     """Broadcast an array to a new shape.
    370 
    371     Parameters
   (...)
    411            [1, 2, 3]])
    412     """
--> 413     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py:349, in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    346     raise ValueError('all elements of broadcast shape must be non-'
    347                      'negative')
    348 extras = []
--> 349 it = np.nditer(
    350     (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
    351     op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
    352 with it:
    353     # never really has writebackifcopy semantics
    354     broadcast = it.itviews[0]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,)  and requested shape (3,2,4,5)
```

If it has the necessary trailing dimensions, then it can perform the 2nd broadcasting step, using 0 strides:

```
In [50]: w = np.broadcast_to(z,x.shape); w.shape
Out[50]: (3, 2, 4, 5)    
In [51]: w.strides
Out[51]: (4, 0, 0, 0)
```

`expand_dims` can also be used, but internally I believe it uses `reshape`.  The code may be instructive:

```
In [52]: np.expand_dims(y,(1,2,3)).shape
Out[52]: (3, 1, 1, 1)
```

`broadcast_to` could be used with the 'reverse' shape to add leading dimensions, and then transposed back.  But that's just your first idea:

```
In [54]: np.broadcast_to(y, x.T.shape).shape
Out[54]: (5, 4, 2, 3)
In [55]: np.broadcast_to(y, x.T.shape).T.shape
Out[55]: (3, 2, 4, 5)    
In [56]: np.broadcast_to(y, x.T.shape).T.strides
Out[56]: (4, 0, 0, 0)
```